# Rewrite the where clause into a Calculated member slicer

Tags: ssas, mdx, cube

could you help me with someting please. I have an MDX query who slice my cube with a Named Set, these results are great, however I need to create a calculated measure and I have not been able to "rewrite" my where clause in the calculated expression.

This MDX works as I need:

```
select non empty [Measures].[Demanda Real] on 0,
non empty [Agente Distribuidor].[Nombre Distribuidor].[Nombre Distribuidor].members on 1
from Demanda
where [SkSubmercadoUsuario]
```

I tried to rewrite the above query and it doesn't work:

```
with member [Measures].[Demanda Real Nueva]
as
([Measures].[Demanda Real],[SkSubmercadoUsuario])
select [Measures].[Demanda Real Nueva] on 0,
non empty [Agente Distribuidor].[Nombre Distribuidor].[Nombre Distribuidor].members on 1
from Demanda
```

Answer (score 0):

If I am correct, you want your measure "[Measures].[Demanda Real]" to always have a filter named set "[SkSubmercadoUsuario]". I translated your senario to adventure works. First run the create set part alone. Then the next two parts, with first part commented

```
create SET [Adventure Works].[testSet] AS ([Geography].[State-Province].&[NY]&[US])
```

Now comment the above part and run

```
Select [Measures].[Reseller Sales Amount] 
on columns, 
non empty
[Product].[Product].[Product]
on rows
from [Adventure Works]
where 
[testSet]
```

Now run the third part

```
with member [Measures].[Test]
as
'('+(settostr([testSet]) ) + ',[Measures].[Reseller Sales Amount])'
Select (strtoset([Measures].[Test]))
on columns,
non empty
[Product].[Product].[Product]
on rows
from [Adventure Works]
```